# Getting the information of a mobile device by connecting to it

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, sql-server-ce, distributed-computing, mobile-devices

Is there any way for a server to obtain some information of the mobile devices that are connected to it like memory size and battery power? Is it possible?

Thanks for any reply in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating an Android app using Apache Cordova and jQuery Mobile, you can use [cordova-plugin-extended-device-information](https://github.com/danielehrhardt/cordova-plugin-extended-device-information) and [cordova-plugin-battery-status](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-battery-status) to get battery status and device's memory size and then send the data to the server using jQuery.post().

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So we, as a server provider, need to have an application that runs on mobile user side, right? I mean it is not possible to get these info without any application running on mobile client side? Sorry if my question is silly, I am not expert on android and mobile computing but I just need to know if it is possible or not, to consider more realistic model in my project.

Comment: I think it's not possible to get those information without the client send it to server. Try this link to get what information that is sent by a browser when connect to a web server . [What HTTP Headers is my browser sending?](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending)